# HEAD Verb in Minimal API C#

Tags: c#, download, configuration, minimal-apis

HEAD

The HTTP HEAD method requests the headers that would be returned if the HEAD
request's URL was instead requested with the HTTP GET method.

> For example, if a URL might produce a large download,a HEAD request could read
> its Content-Length header to check the file-size without actually downloading the file.

My question , how should I get that behavior in my minimal API endpoint.

when-ever I test my API Endpoint in vs-code through Thunder-Client, it return error when I select HEAD VERB

```
405 Method Not Allowed
```

However the downloading is work through GET VERB.

I am very grateful of any example using HEAD VERB, or some settings which maybe I not know to configure.

code in this example is refer from following stack overflow question [ASP.NET Minimal API How to Return/Download Files from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72706391/18648091)

```
app.MapGet(@"download/{fileName}", async (string fileName) =>
{
    var mimeType = "application/zip";
    var path = @$"e:\{fileName}.zip";
    var bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

    return Results.File(bytes, mimeType, $"{fileName}.zip");
})
          .Produces(StatusCodes.Status200OK)
          .Produces(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
          .WithName($"GET {EndpointCategory} by Name")
          .WithTags(Tag);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: No need to ReadAllBytes and allocate memory per request unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MapMethods` with corresponding verb ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0)):

```cs
app.MapMethods(@"download/{fileName}", new[] { "HEAD" }, async (string fileName) => ...);
```

Comment: I use like app.MapMethods("download/{fileName}", new[] { "GET" , "HEAD" } , async (string fileName) =>